# Magento State wise TAX

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, tax-class

I need to setup TAX based on customer shipping state.

Example: If in the USA customer's shipping state is New York then TAX will be 14% otherwise for all state TAX will be 5.5%

I created 2 Tax Rate based on USA state but it's not working.
Anything I forgot to do?

Answer (score 4):

Tax will only working for "Taxable Goods". Make sure you change product information to taxable goods.[image]